AudioManager.getDevices() not work when android application is terminated
I have implemented one Foreground service where application capture location continuously at specified time interval and also find connected audio devices at every location change event.
Everything is working fine as expected but in few android devices (which has latest Android OS 14) like Samsung 23+ application not able to find connected audio devices when application is in terminated state.
I have use below code to find connected audio devices :
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

AudioDeviceInfo[] adi = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);

Note : Everything is working fine when application is in Foreground state but not work when application is in terminated state.
As per document, I have create foreground service and try to find connected bluetooth devices inside foreground service itself but still its not working.
